Solution to series from probability distribution
As part of building some models for a personal project, I defined a variation of the geometric probability distribution where the success probability is different on each trial. In particular, the probability of success of the nth trial is:
$$
p(n) = 1-r^n
$$
for some $r \in (0,1)$. It follows that the probability of failure of the nth trial is simply $r^n$.
With this setup, the probability of succeeding at the nth trial would be:
$$
P(n) = (\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}r^i)(1-r^n)
$$
The next thing I wanted to do is to find the expected number of attempts to succeed. This led to the following series:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n\left(1 - r^{n}\right) \prod_{i = 1}^{n - 1}r^{i}
$$
I did figure out how to reduce the product, like this:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n\left(1 - r^{n}\right) r^{n\left(n - 1\right)/2}
$$
But I still feel I'm nowhere near the solution. Thanks in advance for any tips!
While I did do a math major, that was near two decades ago and I'm a bit rusty on the things that I haven't kept using. That being said, I'm always open to learn more, as math is something I enjoy to practice.
EDIT: I was able to find an expression for the partial sums! It goes like this:
$$
S_{n} = -n\,r^{n\left(n + 1\right)/2}\ +\
\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}r^{i\left(i + 1\right)/2}
$$

So I guess this reduces the problem to finding the limit of $S_{n}$.
And since
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[-n\,r^{n\left(n + 1\right)/2}\,\right] = 0$, that means all that remains to solve is:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}r^{n\left(n + 1\right)/2}
$$


Spliting into two sums leads to the series $\sum r^{n(n-1)/2}.$ After that you have to look at theta series, for instance in 'A brief introduction to Theta functions' Richard Bellman Holt Rinehart and Winston 1961.

What you will find about theta functions is that there is, in general, no way to express a theta function in terms of the familiar functions of undergraduate mathematics (powers, exponentials, logarithms, trig functions...). Mostly all you can do is evaluate them numerically.

Thanks to the link from Felix Marin (comment was removed, this was the link) I was able to get to an answer! Here's how I did it:

I picked the following definition of the theta function:

$$
\vartheta_2(z,q) = 2q^{1/4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^{n(n+1)}\cos[(2n+1)z]
$$
I picked this one because the series in it closely resembles the one in my problem.

Then I set $z = 0$ to get rid of the cosine factor.

$$
\vartheta_2(0,q) = 2q^{1/4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^{n(n+1)}
$$

Then simply by setting $q = r^{1/2}$ I get the target series to appear.

$$
\vartheta_2(0,r^{1/2}) = 2r^{1/8} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{n(n+1)/2}
$$

Now it's just a matter of reordering things to get the solution:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{n(n+1)/2} = \frac{\vartheta_2(0,r^{1/2})}{2r^{1/8}}
$$
From what I understand, this is the closest thing to a solution I can get, even though I'm just writing the series in terms of another one. But I would be happy to be corrected on this.
